# The first RxSwift example fails with "Cannot invoke 'combineLatest' with an argument list ..."

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Trying to wrap my head around RxSwift, but the very first example they provide fails to build.

I'm trying to run the RxSwift code from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Examples.md

```c
let a /*: Observable<Int>*/ = Variable(1)   // a = 1
let b /*: Observable<Int>*/ = Variable(2)   // b = 2

// This will "bind" rx variable `c` to definition
// if a + b >= 0 {
//      c = "\(a + b) is positive"
// }
let c = Observable.combineLatest(a, b) { $0 + $1 }     // combines latest values of variables `a` and `b` using `+`
    .filter { $0 >= 0 }               // if `a + b >= 0` is true, `a + b` is passed to map operator
    .map { "\($0) is positive" }      // maps `a + b` to "\(a + b) is positive"
```

But it fails with error:

> `Cannot invoke 'combineLatest' with an argument list of type '(Variable<Int>, Variable<Int>, (_, _) throws -> _)'`

Is this an error in the example code or am I missing something?

---

Steps I did to reproduce:

1. Create a new iOS Single View Application, save, close it.
2. Create a Podfile in project root, containing:

```
# Podfile
use_frameworks!

pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 2.0'
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 2.0'
pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'RxTests',    '~> 2.0'
```

3. Run `pod install`
4. Open xcworkspace file
5. Put the example code into ViewController's viewDidLoad function:

```c
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let a = Variable(1)
        let b = Variable(2)

        let c = Observable.combineLatest(a, b) { $0 + $1 }
            .filter { $0 >= 0 }
            .map { "\($0) is positive" }
    }
}
```

6. Build. Xcode might complain that it can't load RxSwift. Restart Xcode -> problem solved.
7. Build. Xcode might complain something about bitcode. Disable bitcode everywhere in the project settings -> problem solved.
8. Build. Xcode complains about combineLatest: `Cannot invoke 'combineLatest' ...`

---

Xcode version: 7.2

pod version: 0.39.0

RxSwift version: 2.1.0

---

EDIT: It seems that other examples also fail with various errors, such as:

> Cannot invoke 'concat' with no arguments

Which probably means that something is missing from my project configuration or RxSwift changed dramatically and no one had time to update beginner examples to match the changes. Either way, these were some pretty frustrating first hours with RxSwift.

Answer (score 3):

Observable.combineLatest expects ObservableType(s) where Variable(Int) is a wrapper for a BehaviorSubject. Below I've called .asObservable() on "a" and "b" to allow the code to work.

Check the console output for "3 is positive"

```
    let dispose = DisposeBag()

    let a /*: Observable<Int>*/ = Variable(1)   // a = 1
    let b /*: Observable<Int>*/ = Variable(2)   // b = 2

    let d = a.asObservable()
    let e = b.asObservable()

    let c = Observable.combineLatest(d, e) {
        $0 + $1
        }
        .filter { $0 >= 0 }
        .map { "\($0) is positive" }

    c.subscribe(
        onNext: { i in
            print(i)
        }
    ).addDisposableTo(dispose)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer! So I guess the answer is that there is an error in the RxSwift example?

Comment: Possibly, haven't checked, but ran your code and did a little digging. I might have missed something. Perhaps my pod versions are different also. Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Sure. But that's what I was actually asking in my question. I have problems with other examples as well and I wanna know if there's something I'm doing wrong, you know?

Comment: The outdated example has been updated by kzaher on [this commit](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/commit/a7508fb3a755d172c6e6d2ce1eeaf4dee123de64) to make sure the variables are transformed into observables.